# shinyapps.io “Disconnected from server”/“out of memory” issues

Tags: r, shiny, dashboard, shinydashboard, shinyapps

I am having problems deploying my app on Travis. Here is my app: https://github.com/loicpalma/Shiny_App

You can try it online here: https://loicpalma.shinyapps.io/Test_Shiny/

Basically, when I host my app locally, **everything works perfectly fine**.

However when I try to use it on shinyapps.io I get **disconnected** when trying to do some confusion matrix and so on. It is worth mentionning that I am using the **free** version of shinyapps.io.

Here is my shinyapps.io logs:

```
2019-09-27T21:00:59.412409+00:00 shinyapps[1162708]: 
2019-09-27T21:00:59.412413+00:00 shinyapps[1162708]: Attaching package: ‘shinydashboard’
2019-09-27T21:00:59.412414+00:00 shinyapps[1162708]: 
2019-09-27T21:00:59.412820+00:00 shinyapps[1162708]: The following object is masked from ‘package:graphics’:
2019-09-27T21:00:59.412822+00:00 shinyapps[1162708]: 
2019-09-27T21:00:59.412823+00:00 shinyapps[1162708]:     box
2019-09-27T21:00:59.412823+00:00 shinyapps[1162708]: 
2019-09-27T21:01:00.222691+00:00 shinyapps[1162708]: 
2019-09-27T21:01:00.222705+00:00 shinyapps[1162708]: 
2019-09-27T21:01:00.222703+00:00 shinyapps[1162708]: Attaching package: ‘precrec’
2019-09-27T21:01:00.223080+00:00 shinyapps[1162708]: The following object is masked from ‘package:pROC’:
2019-09-27T21:01:00.223081+00:00 shinyapps[1162708]: 
2019-09-27T21:01:00.223082+00:00 shinyapps[1162708]:     auc
2019-09-27T21:01:00.223082+00:00 shinyapps[1162708]: 
2019-09-27T21:01:00.249436+00:00 shinyapps[1162708]: 
2019-09-27T21:01:00.249440+00:00 shinyapps[1162708]: 
2019-09-27T21:01:00.249837+00:00 shinyapps[1162708]: The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:
2019-09-27T21:01:00.249440+00:00 shinyapps[1162708]: Attaching package: ‘dplyr’
2019-09-27T21:01:00.249838+00:00 shinyapps[1162708]: 
2019-09-27T21:01:00.249839+00:00 shinyapps[1162708]:     filter, lag
2019-09-27T21:01:00.249840+00:00 shinyapps[1162708]: 
2019-09-27T21:01:00.250262+00:00 shinyapps[1162708]: The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:
2019-09-27T21:01:00.250263+00:00 shinyapps[1162708]: 
2019-09-27T21:01:00.250264+00:00 shinyapps[1162708]:     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
2019-09-27T21:01:00.250264+00:00 shinyapps[1162708]: 
2019-09-27T21:01:00.263423+00:00 shinyapps[1162708]: Loading required package: lattice
2019-09-27T21:01:02.014600+00:00 shinyapps[1162708]: 
2019-09-27T21:01:02.014603+00:00 shinyapps[1162708]: Attaching package: ‘xgboost’
2019-09-27T21:01:02.014604+00:00 shinyapps[1162708]: 
2019-09-27T21:01:02.014962+00:00 shinyapps[1162708]: The following object is masked from ‘package:dplyr’:
2019-09-27T21:01:02.014963+00:00 shinyapps[1162708]: 
2019-09-27T21:01:02.014964+00:00 shinyapps[1162708]:     slice
2019-09-27T21:01:02.014965+00:00 shinyapps[1162708]: 
2019-09-27T21:01:02.033009+00:00 shinyapps[1162708]: corrplot 0.84 loaded
2019-09-27T21:01:02.597854+00:00 shinyapps[1162708]: 
2019-09-27T21:01:02.597857+00:00 shinyapps[1162708]: Attaching package: ‘kernlab’
2019-09-27T21:01:02.597858+00:00 shinyapps[1162708]: 
2019-09-27T21:01:02.598774+00:00 shinyapps[1162708]: The following object is masked from ‘package:ggplot2’:
2019-09-27T21:01:02.598775+00:00 shinyapps[1162708]: 
2019-09-27T21:01:02.598776+00:00 shinyapps[1162708]: 
2019-09-27T21:01:02.598775+00:00 shinyapps[1162708]:     alpha
2019-09-27T21:01:02.626321+00:00 shinyapps[1162708]: 
2019-09-27T21:01:02.626323+00:00 shinyapps[1162708]: Please cite as: 
2019-09-27T21:01:02.626324+00:00 shinyapps[1162708]: 
2019-09-27T21:01:02.626480+00:00 shinyapps[1162708]:  Hlavac, Marek (2018). stargazer: Well-Formatted Regression and Summary Statistics Tables.
2019-09-27T21:01:02.626656+00:00 shinyapps[1162708]:  R package version 5.2.2. https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=stargazer 
2019-09-27T21:01:02.626657+00:00 shinyapps[1162708]: 
2019-09-27T21:01:07.171025+00:00 shinyapps[1162708]: 
2019-09-27T21:01:07.171029+00:00 shinyapps[1162708]: Listening on http://127.0.0.1:35874
2019-09-27T21:03:20.162037+00:00 shinyapps[1162708]: Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
2019-09-27T21:03:22.338070+00:00 shinyapps[system]: Out of memory!
```

Apparently this is an `"Out of memory issue"`.

Here are my shinyapps.io settings:

[image]

[image]

Here are my metrics:

[image]

I am using a 50 Mb .rds dataset that I load directly in the global.R so I don't think this is the problem.

I see that a lot of people have been going through this kind of problem. However, I didn't find any solution on stackoverflow. Does anybody have a solution to this “Disconnected from server”/“out of memory” issue ?

Comment: looks like you need [more ram](https://community.rstudio.com/t/shinyapps-system-out-of-memory-even-after-upgrading-to-8gb-plan/33213/3). Also check [this](https://docs.rstudio.com/shinyapps.io/applications.html#memory).

Comment: @NewUser how do I increase the "instance size"? I mean it won't work anyway. I get disconnected when I try to render some confusion matrix.